# Spring push send message over WebSocket to unauthenticated user

Tags: java, spring-websocket

I am using Spring with Spring-Security.
I have a situation where I would want to push send a message over WebSocket to a specific user by session *before* the user is authenticated.

Usually tutorials are on situations where messages are send reacting on some incoming messages so that doesn't really help me.

I tried to find a way to get access to the WebSocketSession object associated with some session but couldn't find a way to do so; honestly I am not even sure if that would be the way to go to implement what I want.

Is there any "common-practice" to achieve what I want in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look into Spring Security Filter Chain mechanics. You can hook into any step of the FilterChain using `httpSecurit.addFilterBefore()` `httpSecurit.addFilterAt()` `httpSecurit.addFilterAfter()`. Add your filter before the AUTH step and do what ever you want to do.

You will find good examples for this if you google up JWT and spring. There usually one has to put a custom filter for JWTTokenGeneration on username password auth.

You could use SSE to send a push notification to the socket in that filter step.